# making the circular avatar show at the top of the screen

Tags: flutter, dart, user-interface

[image: see image here]

How can I make the circleavatar to be placed at the top of the container

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use `Stack` for this. like:

```dart
...
return Stack(
  children: [
    Positioned.filled( child:
    Scaffold(
      appBar: ...
      body: Column([
        DecoratedBox(
          ...
        )
      ]),
    )),
    Positioned(
      top: 24,
      child:
        CircleAvatar( child:
          CachedNetworkImage(
            ...
          ),
        ),
    ),
  ],
);
```

something like that.

Answer (score 0):

Try below code hope its helpful to you.refer `Stack` class [here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Stack-class.html)

```
 Stack(
        alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
        children: <Widget>[
          Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 21),
            child: Container(
              height: 200,
              width: double.infinity,
              child: Card(
                shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                ),
                color: Colors.white,
                margin: EdgeInsets.all(
                  16,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Container(
            width: 100,
            height: 90,
            decoration: ShapeDecoration(
              shape: CircleBorder(),
              color: Colors.transparent,
            ),
            child: CircleAvatar(),
          )
        ],
      ),
```

Your result screen-> [image]